# shortest distance from a point $\vec{r}_0$ to the line between $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$.

Tags: vectors

In my head the answer should be given by $\big|\vec{r}_0-\vec{r}_2\big|\sin(\theta)$ which would be

$$
\frac{\big|(\vec{r}_0-\vec{r}_2)\times(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2)\big|}{\big|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\big|}
$$

my book says it is

$$
\frac{\big|(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_0)\times(\vec{r}_2-\vec{r}_0)\big|}{|\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2|}
$$

Comment: So the above numerators must be of the same value? :)

Comment: Perhaps but I'm not sure where their expression comes from as there's no proof given so i don't know how I can show that

Comment: $(r_0-r_2)\times(r_1-r_2)=(r_0-r_2)\times(r_1-r_0+r_0-r_2)= (r_0-r_2)\times(r_1-r_0)+(r_0-r_2)\times(r_0-r_2)=(r_1-r_0)\times(r_2-r_0)+0$

Comment: Well the cross product is only defined for three dimensional vectors...so this can't be the best possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance between $r_2$ and $r_o$ is simply $$\left| r_2-r_0\right|$$ And between $r_1$ and $r_0$ it is $$\left| r_1-r_0\right|$$ Notice $r_2$, $r_1$ and $r_0$ form an isosceles triangle which has half the area of the corresponding parallelogram. So the area of the triangle they form is $$\frac{\left| (r_2-r_0)\wedge (r_1-r_0)\right|}{2}$$ Using the classic, $area=\frac{1}{2}base*height$, notice the base is simply given by the vector $r_2-r_1$ and the height, which is what you're after, can now be found. $$\frac{1}{2}\left|r_2-r_1\right|D = \frac{\left| (r_2-r_0)\wedge (r_1-r_0)\right|}{2}$$ and so the perpendicular distance, $D$ is given by $$D= \frac{\left| (r_2-r_0)\wedge (r_1-r_0)\right|}{\left|r_2-r_1\right|}$$